# MySQL nested selects, X and Y

Tags: mysql, select

So im trying to get into MySQL and i'm doing the SQLZoo Tutorials.

There's this one exercise that introduces some new techniques (FROM world x and FROM world y) - what does x and y do here?

Could someone break down the code line for line for me?
All help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT continent, name, population FROM world x
  WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population FROM world y
        WHERE y.continent=x.continent
          AND population>0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is alias. In this example x.continent is this same as world.continent.
But in subquery y.contintent is this same as wordl.continent. With aliases you can join this same table

Answer (score 1):

`x` and `y` are effectively names for your result sets so they can be referred to without any ambiguity.

Similarly, if you are doing a `JOIN` on two tables which both have the same column name (e.g. a `customer` table and an `order` table which both have an `id_customer` field), you will refer to the table name and then the column name (e.g. `order.id_customer`, to make it clear you are not referring to `customer.id_customer`)